# Concept design-pattern for industry simulation required

Tags: unity, mathematics, game-mechanics, design-patterns, mobile

I am making a mobile game simulating industry. A brief high level description is below.
A hub could be thought of as a base/city, within which there are rooms/buildings which determine what is produced and consumed.
Rooms/buildings need people to work them.
People have their own produced and consumed resources that need to come from rooms/buildings.
The buildings like machines in a production line have paths of commodity flow defined.
How to implement people with their own needs like thirst, sleep and illness while coordinating the buildings is causing me trouble.
I know many games have this same premise but can’t turn up enough info on their workings to help me. The real challenge is that I do not want to run the game where time passes relatively slowly and each person can move around and make decisions constantly.  I want to be able to change the speed of the game, likely from running a day every 30 seconds to a month every two minutes. So was focusing more on when changes to the system were occurring.
The number of hubs is likely to reach 80 each with 20 rooms and say 30 people to give an idea of scale.
Do you have any example games or coding approaches that could help light my way? Each concept I think through falls over.
Your help is very much appreciated and thanks for reading! If I have not included enough details please let me know, it is my first post so unsure how far to go into it.

Comment: I think you should get to grips with coding more basic games, like a Pong or Pacman, which will teach you how time-slicing between entities works, before you try to tackle something more complex like this.

Comment: Thank you Engineer, time slicing is not something I had learnt about and will be valuable. Time slicing type approaches will definitely help manage the scaling of the project to mitigate lag.